# Unused argument in R

Tags: r

I am using R Studio and creating some vectors and doing some calculations with them. However, when I execute the code, I get the `unused argument` error. How can I solve this issue?

```
f <- c(2,4,6) 
v <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
cos(c(0, pi/4, pi/2, pi))
```

[image: Error]

Comment: This question is about R language, right?

Comment: Could you explain your question better?

Comment: Yes, I am using Rstudio.

Comment: Is this everything? If it was only `f <- c(2,4,6)`, then it would surely work.

Comment: I think something wrong occur in my console, even some simple input does not give right output.

Comment: which libraries did you call? does it still happen if you restart R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable might exist in your R workspace. What you could do is to start from a clean session or try typing `rm("c")` in your console and this will solve your problem. It cleans `c` from the workspace.

Comment: problem sloved! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice to help! Please accept this answer at the check icon!